# How to extract specific rows from pandas dataframe using without duplicate after condition?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

please help me on this i need proper python code for satisfy these condition in image:
**Condition = If "Message" is having > 1 "Category" then Save those entire rows in new data frame**

**But it should not save the the rows if message is having only one Category repeatedly**

```
df[df.duplicated(['Message'], keep=False)]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuWVV.png)

I have tried this duplicate concept but it prints all the values including if message is having only one Category repeatedly

**I need proper python code for same output file format in image**

Comment: please reformat your question.  No images.  Provide us with code to reproduce your dataframe so we can help answer your question.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for here. Is it accurate to say you want to filter your dataframe down to only those rows corresponding to "Message"s which in turn are associated with more than one value in the "Category" column"?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two lines: first remove the duplicates where both `Message` and `Category` are the same, then find all duplicates of `Message` with unique `Category`:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Message', 'Category'])
df[df.duplicated(subset='Message', keep=False)]
```

**Edit:**
In the case that the naive `drop_duplicates` method removes valid data (it works coincidentally for your example but may run into issues for larger data) you can explicitly apply the condition for unique `Category`:

```
valid = df.groupby('Message').Category.transform('nunique') > 1
df[df.duplicated(subset='Message', keep=False) & valid]
```

It ends up also being two lines which is nice but it is a bit more complicated to read through. What's happening is we are grouping the DataFrame by `Message` to determine which of them have multiple `Category` unique values. We specifically use the groupby `transform` method to make it a shape that works with axis zero of our original data, using it as a boolean mask with the condition `> 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your dataset as follows:

```py
data = {
        "Message": [
            "I like this product",
            "I am going to buy",
            "Quality is good",
            "Nice product",
            "Its weight is high",
            "I like this product",
            "Its working",
            "love it",
            "Design is good",
            "Its working",
            "Design is good",
            "Design is good",
            "Design is good",
            "Design is good"
            ],
        "Category": [
            "Satisfaction",
            "Intent",
            "Product Quality",
            "Product Quality",
            "Weight",
            "Product Quality",
            "Performance",
            "Satisfaction",
            "Design",
            "Product Quality",
            "Design",
            "Design",
            "Design",
            "Design"
            ],
        }
```

Then we can find all the unique values in your `df["Message"]` column and determine which of them have more than one unique value associated with them in the `df['Category']` column:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
messages = df.Message.unique()

multi_category = []
for message in messages:
    subset = len(df[df["Message"] == message]["Category"].unique())
    if subset > 1:
        multi_category.append(message)

final = df[df["Message"].isin(multi_category)]
print(final)
```

Finally we filter our `DataFrame` by the "Message" column and get the following output:

```
               Message         Category
0  I like this product     Satisfaction
5  I like this product  Product Quality
6          Its working      Performance
9          Its working  Product Quality
```